# Google Maps API V3 geocode javascript if json value exists

Tags: javascript, json, api, maps, geocode

I am somewhat a novice with Javascript and I am trying to create a very simple if statement.

I am sending an address to the google geocoder and receiving the json result. I'm parsing the result and printing into my html document.

I now only want to attempt to print values that actually exist to keep from crashing my code.

right now I have:

```
document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML = [results[1].geometry.location.lat()];
```

and it works, but I don't want that line to run if "results[1].geometry.location.lat()" doesn't exist in the json result.

I have tried:

```
if ([results[1].geometry.location.lat()] != null) {
    document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML = [results[1].geometry.location.lat()];    
}
```

but the line still runs even if there is no value there. I gotta be doing this wrong. Please help someone.

Because the value will be different every time, I just want the line to run if there is ANY value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that geometry exists but you are unsure if location exists or not, you can check against undefined.

```
if (results[0].geometry.location !== undefined) {
    var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
}
```

If you don't know if even geomery exists, then you would also need to check if that is undefined.

Comment: I would like to know if even geometry exists.

Answer (score 1):

`[results[1].geometry.location.lat()]` is shorthand for an array; it will never be null.

Take out the `[]`.

The truly safe way to test would be:

```
if (results[1] && results[1].geometry && results[1].geometry.location && results[1].geometry.location.lat) {
   ...
```

Comment: Hi awn, thanks for your response, but it doesn't seem to work, I'm actually trying to say if the postal code exists in a certain array then print that value. here's the exact code i tried. I know that there is no 7th array for address_components and the line still ran and error'd in ie  if (results[0] && results[0].address_component[7] && results[0].address_components[7].short_name) {document.getElementById('zip_r').innerHTML = [
   results[0].address_components[7].short_name];
   }

Comment: You need to check if address_component is an array before you try to reference part of it:  `if (results[0] && typeOf(results[0].address_component)==="array" && ...`